# JavatoC#(Timestamp)

Tags: c#, java, timestamp

I have this code in Java and I want to convert it to C#. Please help me.

```
public virtual Timestamp getMinProstyTimeStamp(string sCurrFieldName, string sWellName)
        {
            Timestamp tsMinDate = new Timestamp(0);
            // If field name have not changed, there is no need to recreate the qds
            if (!sFieldName.ToLower().Equals(sCurrFieldName))
            {
                createQdsWellAlias(sCurrFieldName);
            }
            QueryDataSet qds = getQdsWellAlias(sWellName);
            if (!qds.Empty)
            {
                tsMinDate = qds.getTimestamp("MINDATE");
            }
            return tsMinDate;
        }
```

Comment: what data type is MINDATE in your data base

Comment: You could try this http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/977781/Microsoft-Launches-Java-to-C-Converter.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use TimeSpan like this:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.MinValue;
```